# Как убрать ID реферера из URL в Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Есть проект на Yii2. Есть пользователи, которые могут перейти по реферальной ссылке. Реферальная ссылка вида **`example.com/99`** (`id` реферала = `99`). При переходе на сайт отрабатывает сделующее правило конфига:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
        '<id:\d+>' => 'site/index',
    ],
],
```

И дальше я спокойно работаю с этим `id` в `SiteController::actionIndex()`. Вопрос в том, возможно ли при переходе на сайт по данной ссылке, убрать этот `id` из URL? Т.е. пользователь переходит, отрабатывает правило, в `actionIndex()` идут действия и рендериться `index.php`, а пользователь видит индекс, но в адресной строке только **`example.com`**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать редирект:

```
public function actionIndex($id = null)
{
    if ($id) {
        // Добавляем `id` реферера в сессию или 
        // выполняем другие нужные манипуляции.
        Yii::$app->session['refererId'] = $id;
        return $this->goHome();
    }
    return $this->render('index');
}
```

Можно использовать `pushState`.

Comment: Да, суть именно такая что id сохраняется, правда в куку) А это не плохо лишнюю перезагрузку лепить?

Comment: @OlegShleif, если у вас не супер нагруженный проект, то ничего страшного. Ну или сделайте с помощью `pushState`. Ну или где-нибудь раньше контроллера ... А перезагрузки не будет только используя `pushState`; иначе же как изменить адрес, если он на клиенте, а скрипт на сервере — только сделать редирект.

Comment: То же верно... Спасибо большое